# Sort by multiple rows containng "NA"

Tags: r, awk

I have orthologous gene clustering in three different viral species, that looks something like this (header cluster_name position_sp1 position_sp2 position_sp3):

```
gene1 100 110 90
gene2 200 230 195
gene3 NA 270 NA
gene4 NA 250 245
gene5 NA NA 230
gene6 250 NA 270
```

I want to sort by position of species1, until I hit an "NA" occurrance in sp1.

1. When an "NA" is encountered in sp1, rows that are not "NA" from
   sp2 are added based on the last position of sp2 when sp1 wasn't
   "NA".
2. When an "NA" is encountered in sp1 and sp2, rows from sp3
   are added that are larger than the last position of sp3 when either
   sp1 or sp2 werent "NA".
3. sp2 rows can't get added when sp1 isn't "NA"
4. sp3 can't get added when sp2 isn't "NA"

Not sure if this makes a whole lot of sense but based on example above, output should be:

```
gene1 100 110 90
gene2 200 230 195
gene4 NA 250 245
gene3 NA 270 NA
gene5 NA NA 230
gene6 250 NA 270
```

Is there anyway to sort this way?

Comment: where would `gene10 NA 210 200` be sorted to?

Comment: ++@SAFEX, Also, whether it depends on its initial position?

Comment: for internal consistency sake, I would have expected gene6 to be the third record after sorting.  Current logic depends on initial order and will be non-uniform handling of the first sort column from the others.

Comment: @SAFEX; gene10 NA 210 200 would be sorted right after gene2 and before gene4, as it has the smallest sp2 position when sp1 is NA.

Comment: @karakfa; you bring about an interesting point. The logic needs to be retaught. Let's say first step is to sort based on sp1 coordinates and exclude sp1 "NA", making list 1. Whenever sp1 is "NA" but not sp2, those rows are then individually added to List1, in such a way that each sp2 position is added right after the List1 coordinate where sp2 position was smaller, making List2. Lastly when sp1 and sp2 are "NA", every sp3 record is added to List2 after the first smaller sp3 record in List2 making List3. This seems like it should always give the same result no?

Comment: Add the pseudo-code for your algorithm to your question so at least you'll have provided some kind of attempt to solve it yourself and then I expect we'll be able to help you translate that to awk.